# parsing german numbers within string-vector

Tags: r, parsing, readr, tidyverse

Having a string as follows:

```
x <- c("31.12.2009EUR", "31.12.2009", "23.753,38", "0,00")
```

I would like to parse it as

```
c(NA, NA, 23753.38, 0.00)
```

I tried:

```
require(readr)
parse_number(x, locale=locale(decimal_mark = ",")) # This ignores the grouping_mark
#> 31122009.00 31122009.00    23753.38        0.00

parse_double(x, locale=locale(decimal_mark = ","))
#> NA NA NA  0
```

The only way i came up with:

```
out <- rep(NA, length(x))
ind <- grep("^[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{3})*\\,[0-9]{2}", x)
out[ind] <- parse_number(x[ind],locale=locale(decimal_mark = ","))
out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner uses no packages and no complex regular expressions.  It assumes the valid elements have a comma and the invalid ones not.  This works with the sample input shown but if not in your real data just use a more complex regex in `grepl` based on whatever the criterion is.

```
as.numeric(ifelse(grepl(",", x), chartr(",", ".", gsub(".", "", x, fixed = TRUE)), NA))
## [1]       NA       NA 23753.38     0.00
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. @GGrothendieck why do you use `chartr` instead of sub(..., fixed=TRUE)?